# Does Celery works properly on old version of django?

Tags: python, django, celery

I am using `django 1.3.3` for my web app and for the time being I don't want to migrate to newer version, I want schedule periodic tasks to shoot e-mails to the users.

I found celery is the best choice but I have few concerns.

1. Does celery works on old versions of django (1.3.3)?
2. Other than Celery is there any other django app that serves my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery *can* work fine, but you may have to pin it to an earlier version if there are compatibility issues with 1.3 and recent versions of Celery.

Back when I was using 1.3, I used [this gist](https://gist.github.com/stevejalim/3341071) to note which version of Celery I needed. I can't promise that's 100% reliable, but it did work for me at the time.

*HOWEVER* pinning to older versions isn't really a good move: there may be security fixes in more recent versions of Celery, for instance. (There certainly have been a few for Django, and 1.3.x is no longer maintained with them, so [upgrading to 1.4.13 LTS](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) at least is worth it.)

Let me say that again, in a different way:

"for the time being I don't want to migrate to newer version" isn't a good enough reason to leave a production app on an old version of a framework, if there are known security issues in the field (and there are). The minor pain of upgrading is preferable to bugs or security issues that may arise if you leave things as they are. 1.3.3 isn't even them most up to date 1.3 branch release...

Take the work on the chin and upgrade, at last to 1.4.13 (it's not a big upgrade, so should be pretty painless)

In terms of alternatives to Celery, I happen to prefer [rq](https://github.com/nvie/rq/) - thought it does require Redis, while Celery is more flexible about its backends.